# Need assistance with Typescript Modules bundling

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundler, node-modules, rollupjs

I am currently developing a Typescript application using lit html. I have reached the point where I want to bundle all my typescript files, minimize them in to a single javascript file. Using VS Code as the IDE.

I have been looking at options - rollup.js is one option but I couldn't work out how to bundle multiple ts files in to a single js file, minimize it and also ensure the modules are handled correctly.

Any examples of using rollup.js to do such available or another alternative available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parcel js](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) for this as well. This will generate one js file. but if you require rollup js, may be this link will help you out.
[Generate typescript definition files using rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329876/generate-typescript-definition-files-using-rollup)

Comment: Parcel will handle the Typescript modules and work with node packages?